# Regex problem in Java in code sample

Tags: java, regex

I have job with regex in my expressions: example `!(FA1_A.i & FA1_M.i)`

I have operators:  `! ( ) & |`

The operands have names: `[a-zA-Z_]*\.[a-zA-Z_]`

I wrote Java code to split on tokens, but it doesn't split on operators and operands. It should be !, (, FA1_A.i, &, FA1_m.i, ) . Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

```
String stringOpĐµrator = "([!|&()])";
String stringOperand = "(([a-zA-Z_]*)\\.([a-zA-Z_]*))";
String reg=stringOpĐµrator+"|"+stringOperand;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reg);

Matcher m = pattern.matcher(expression);
// System.out.println("func: " + function + " item: " + item);
while (m.find()) {
    int a=m.start();
    int b=m.end();
    String test=expression.substring(m.start(), m.end());
    String g=test;
    tokens.add(new Token(expression.substring(m.start() , m.end())));


            //m = pattern.matcher(expression);

        }
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What do you expect it to do? What happens instead? Simply saying "It doesn't work" is not exactly helpful ...

Comment: "Đµ" suggests you have an encoding issue somewhere, which could be affecting how your regexes operate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names in the example you've given appear to contain numbers, which your regex doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change following code

```
String stringOperand = "(([a-zA-Z_]*)\\.([a-zA-Z_]*))";
```

**TO**

```
String stringOperand = "(([a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\\.([a-zA-Z_0-9]*))";
```